# How can I fetch data from a website (e.g. IMDB ) using Ajax in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, imdb

I am developing a site for thriller movies. I want to fetch data from IMDB. I need to use Ajax to fetch data asynchronously. My code does not work well.

The movie info is not appearing in the carousal.
The html file which fetch data :

```
  <?php
       require_once('functions.php'); 
       $triangle = getMovieInfo('triangle');
       $Predestination = getMovieInfo('Predestination');
       $silence_of_the_lambs = getMovieInfo('The Silence of the Lambs');
       $shutter_island = getMovieInfo('Shutter Island');
    ?>
    <br>
  <!-- Text which has greater value -->
    <div>
      <div class = "row">
        <div class="alert alert-success text-center" role="alert"><h3>If you are looking for a site, where you can see the list of all verified thrillers, then you are at the right place.</h3></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- slider for the home page -->

        <div class="container">

      <div class="row">
        <div class = "col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
          <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

              <div class="item active">
                <?php  echo "<img src=\"$triangle->Poster\">"; ?>
                <!-- <span> <?php echo "Plot : ".$triangle->Plot; ?> </span> -->
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <?php  echo "<img src=\"$silence_of_the_lambs->Poster\">"; ?>
                 <!-- <span> <?php echo "Plot : ".$silence_of_the_lambs->Plot; ?> </span> -->
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <?php  echo "<img src=\"$Predestination->Poster\">"; ?>
                 <!-- <span> <?php echo "Plot : ".$Predestination->Plot; ?> </span> -->
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <?php  echo "<img src=\"$shutter_island->Poster\">"; ?>
                 <!-- <span> <?php echo "Plot : ".$shutter_island->Plot; ?> </span> -->
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Left and right controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
          </div>  
          </div>
          <div class ="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
             <div class="well">
              <div class="thriller">
                  <h3>What is a thriller movie?</h3>
                  <h4>If the genre is to be defined strictly, a genuine thriller is a film that rentlessly pursues a single-minded goal - to provide thrills and keep the audience cliff-hanging at the 'edge of their seats' as the plot builds towards a climax.</h4>
                  <h4>
                   Believe me, I love watching thriller movies more than anything. These movies are real movies, where you can't guess the last scene. I enjoyed a lot of thriller movies and then thought to make a site, where you can easily watch a movie.
                  </h4>
              </div>
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

The getMovieInfo function is here:
function getMovieInfo($title)
      {
        $title = urlencode($title);

```
    //Call the omdb api
    $json=file_get_contents("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=$title");

    $details=json_decode($json);

    //Check if response contains the movie information
    if($details->Response=='True')
    {   

        return $details;

    }

    else 
    {
         echo "Movie information not available.Please confirm title";
    }

  }
```

My java script file is:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
  $("#home").click(function(event)
  {
      alert("home is clicked");
      $('#contents').load('home.html');
  });


});
```

[image: The movies info is not printed.]
Please help me to solve this.

Comment: "My code does not work well." Realy? What about some specific problem, error message etc?

Comment: I am adding a screen shot..

Comment: What if you actually get rid of all these `<!-- <span> <?php echo "Plot : ".$variable->Plot; ?> </span> -->`?

Comment: Nothing happened, content id contains:

Comment: try changing your quote positions: `echo "<img src='\$triangle->Poster\'>";`

Comment: Nothing happens same problem @Michiel, I think that home.html should be home.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file needs to be .php, not .html as you are using PHP in your code.

Don't worry though, HTML will still be parsed as normal.